# Controlling play/pause actions of javascript mp3 player within a frame from other iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

I had an webradio project for a client, so I need to put in a mainpage (index.html) one iframe with the audio stream and another iframe with the Wordpress webradio page to guarantee the audio won't reload with the page navigation between the site.

The problem is: the "stop button" its on the webradio page iframe, so even if I target the "a" for the audio stream iframe, it doesn't work. I read some of topics here and tried "parent.document" too but nothing works. Can someone give me some light?

The page in question:
http://radiotalent.com.br/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have two `IFrame`s inside a root document, following this disposition:

- Root document

  - IFrame1
  - IFrame2

If you want to call, say, a method located in `IFrame2` from `IFrame1`, then `parent` is indeed your friend. The code in `IFrame1` would look something like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("IFrame2").contentWindow.Method();
```

The following marker code indicate the position of each member on the above line:

```
^ [parent (Root)]
       ^ [parent document]
                ^ [The target frame]
                                          ^ [The window object in the frame]
                                                        ^ [The JS method itself]
```

Now, keep in mind that you won't be able to use this if the IFrames reference content in different domains because of the *"Same Origin" security policy*.

Comment: Dear god! I never know that policy. Read about it here and that was the problem why its not working. Thank you so much for remind me that OnoSendai, saved my day! ;)

Comment: You're always welcome, @fkrust, and sorry to hear that you won't be able to implement it that way. Maybe you can use URL poisoning to pass parameters?

Answer (score 0):

From the webradio frame call iframe1.stop() function. That might help.

Comment: Use jquery for "stop button" click event to interact with the outside audio frame seems not work, he doesn't "find".

Comment: It should work, but don't use jQuery, just call the function referencing the frame. I've done yhis lot of times and it works.

Answer (score 0):

think of it this way. If you have two iframes, your connection is the parent page.

What you'd want to do, lets assume you're using regular javascript at first (consider JQUERY THOUGH)

Say you have iframe 1, with an ID of "iframe1" and the second "iframe2"

to access iframe2 from iframe1

```
var iframe2 = parent.document.getElementById("iframe2");
```

or the other way around

```
var iframe1 = parent.document.getElementById("iframe1");
```

EDIT:

X-FRAME-OPTIONS STRIKES AGAIN, seems the poster was trying to have cross-domain access when this is specifically denied by iframes when the sites use this particular protection.

Comment: Thats should work it too, since jQuery inside iframe wont fint external iframes in the parent pages. But in my specific case, was "Same Origin" security policy problem, but thanks anyway, Mike.

Comment: Your particular problem can be fixed with using Div's and content queries, instead of using iframes. Iframes are a nasty bit of business, and should be avoided when possible.